# How to fix 'Attempt to invoke 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference' error in Android

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to setup a new custom ArrayAdapter for a layout element in Android (something that I have done dozens of times) but it seems I've been getting a null object reference error somewhere in my code whenever I start the activity.

I have checked every detail and nothing seems to be out of the ordinary.

My CustomAdapter file (CustomAdapterRangliste):

```
package ba.unsa.etf.rma.klase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ba.unsa.etf.rma.R;

public class CustomAdapterRangliste extends ArrayAdapter<RangLista> {
    private Context mContext;
    private int resources;
    private ArrayList<RangLista> rang;

    public CustomAdapterRangliste(Context context, int res, ArrayList<RangLista> rang) {
        super(context, res, rang);
        mContext = context;
        resources = res;
        this.rang = rang;
    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rangliste, parent, false);
         //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_igraj_kviz_akt, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etRangliste);
        final RangLista rangIgraca = rang.get(position);
        textView.setText(rangIgraca.toString());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The layout element (rangliste.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etRangliste"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="696dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code that I use to initialize and bind the CustomAdapter (in an activity implementing the fragment):

```java
  final ListView rangLista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRanglista);
        final ArrayList<RangLista> ranking = new ArrayList<>();
        final CustomAdapterRangliste rangAdapter = new CustomAdapterRangliste(this, R.layout.rangliste, ranking);
        rangLista.setAdapter(rangAdapter);
```

The layout file with the ListView element (fragment_ranglista.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragmenti.RanglistaFrag">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRanglista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#4FD80000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment file:

```java
package ba.unsa.etf.rma.fragmenti;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ba.unsa.etf.rma.R;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link RanglistaFrag.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link RanglistaFrag#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class RanglistaFrag extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public RanglistaFrag.OnFragmentInteractionListener2 mListener;
    public void postaviListener (RanglistaFrag.OnFragmentInteractionListener2 mListener)
    {
        this.mListener=mListener;
    }
    public RanglistaFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ba.unsa.etf.rma.fragmenti.RanglistaFrag.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static RanglistaFrag newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RanglistaFrag fragment = new RanglistaFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ranglista, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    /*    if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        /*if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
       // mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener2 {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void azuriranjeRangliste();
    }
}
```

*I can't figure out what I've been doing wrong, none of the similar questions helped me, I checked for lines that were left out but without success*

Comment: @GhostCat How is it a duplicate, I am certainly not a beginner who's unfamiliar with the particular error type, I've had multiple people (with years of experience) review this code, none of which happened to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that when you call this `rangLista.setAdapter(rangAdapter);` the variable `rangLista` is null. This can happen in multiple ways, but what I'd check first is if you're inflating the correct layout, because most likely the line `findViewById(R.id.lvRanglista);` is returning null.

Check if your layout file contains the list view with the id you're using in `findViewById`.

Comment: Updated the question with the code, it does contain the list view.

Comment: @123rightback123 can you also add the place where you inflate the layout and the name of the layout files pls?

Comment: Added the names, the inflation should happen in the CustomAdapterRangliste I guess, I used the same approach in my other custom adapters. This ListView is in a fragment layout, if you have any suggestions please say so.

Comment: @123rightback123 is `fragment_ranglista.xml` inflated in the fragment where you do `findViewById(R.id.lvRanglista)`? Could you also add this part of the code pls?

Comment: Yes it is: `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ranglista, container, false);
    }`

Comment: Could you post the entire fragment code? It might be that you're doing this too early in the lifecycle.

Comment: I'm confused. Where's the `findViewById`?

Comment: Where would I need it, I'm not communicating with the layout through the fragment?

Comment: The easiest is to use it inside the fragment in `onCreateView` after inflating the view. This would be then `final ListView rangLista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvRanglista);` where `view` is the result of `inflate`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure TextView is linked with the ID  in R.layout.rangliste file

Comment: Isn't it though? I used etRangliste in the adapter file.